# Android chatting app getMessages returns null

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I m trying to make a chatting app in android studio. I have partially finished the project but I came across this error, which I am unable to figure out. The problem is that whenever I use `.getMessage()` it returns a null value.

The codes are given below

**ChatAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    ArrayList<MessagesModel> messagesModels;
    Context context;
    int SENDER_VIEW_TYPE = 1;
    int RECEIVER_VIEW_TYPE = 2;

    public ChatAdapter(ArrayList<MessagesModel> messagesModels, Context context) {
        this.messagesModels = messagesModels;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == SENDER_VIEW_TYPE){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_sender, parent,false);
            return  new SenverViewHolder(view);
        }
        else{
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_sender, parent,false);
            return  new ReceiverViewHolder(view);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       return  SENDER_VIEW_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MessagesModel messagesModel = messagesModels.get(position);
        System.out.println(messagesModel.getMessage());
        if (holder.getClass() == SenverViewHolder.class){
            ((SenverViewHolder)holder).senderMsg.setText(messagesModel.getMessage());
        }else {
            ((ReceiverViewHolder)holder).receiverMsg.setText(messagesModel.getMessage());
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messagesModels.size();
    }

    public class ReceiverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView receiverMsg, receiverTime;
        public ReceiverViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            receiverMsg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiverText);
            receiverTime= itemView.findViewById(R.id.reciverTime);
        }
    }
    public class SenverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView senderMsg, senderTime;
        public SenverViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            senderMsg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.senderText);
            senderTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.senderTime);
        }
    }
}
```

**MessagesModel.java**

```
public class MessagesModel {
    String uId,message;
    Long timestamp;
    public MessagesModel() {}

    public MessagesModel(String uID, String Message) {
        super();
        this.uId = uID;
        this.message = Message;
    }

    public String getuId() {
        return uId;
    }

    public void setuId(String uId) {
        this.uId = uId;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        System.out.println("Message "+message);
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Long getTimestamp() { return timestamp; }

    public void setTimestamp(Long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

**UsersAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<Users> list;
    Context context;

    public UsersAdapter(ArrayList<Users> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_show_user,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Users users = list.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(users.getProfilepic()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_supervised_user_circle_24).into(holder.image);
        holder.userName.setText(users.getUsername());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent( context, chatDetailedActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userId", users.getUserId("user"));
                intent.putExtra("profileic", users.getProfilepic());
                intent.putExtra("username", users.getUsername());
                context.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView userName, lastMessage;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userNameList);
            lastMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lestMessage);
        }
    }

}
```

**ChatDetailedActivity.java**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.vroo.databinding.ActivityChatDetailedBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class chatDetailedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityChatDetailedBinding binding;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityChatDetailedBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        final String senderId = auth.getUid();
        String receiveId = getIntent().getStringExtra("userId");
        String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        String profilePic = getIntent().getStringExtra("profileic");

        binding.ChatUsername.setText(username);
        Picasso.get().load(profilePic).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_supervised_user_circle_24).into(binding.profileImage);

        binding.backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(chatDetailedActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        final ArrayList<MessagesModel> messagesModel = new ArrayList<>();
        final ChatAdapter chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(messagesModel,this);
        binding.RecycleView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        binding.RecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        final String senderRoom = senderId + receiveId;
        final String receiverRoom = receiveId + senderId;

        database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderRoom).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                messagesModel.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot1:snapshot.getChildren()){
                    MessagesModel model = snapshot.getValue(MessagesModel.class);
                    messagesModel.add(model);
                }
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        binding.send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = binding.editTextTextMultiLine.getText().toString();
                final MessagesModel model = new MessagesModel(senderId,message);
                binding.editTextTextMultiLine.setText("");

                database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderRoom).push().setValue(model).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                        database.getReference().child("chats").child(receiverRoom).push().setValue(model).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Database JSON File**

```
{
  "User" : {
    "7V43IzF3QBh4wtn3NG6gW0xxNR03" : {
      "mail" : "gelk@gmail.com",
      "password" : "4547777",
      "username" : "hello"
    },
    "PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h1" : {
      "mail" : "neil@gmail.com",
      "password" : "123456",
      "username" : "neil"
    },
    "iK6zuVXOSqNLGi75XmXaM16jrxI2" : {
      "mail" : "gkjkjkjelk@gmail.com",
      "password" : "4547777",
      "username" : "hejkllo"
    }
  },
  "chats" : {
    "7V43IzF3QBh4wtn3NG6gW0xxNR03PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h1" : {
      "-MfCf3cXc0dsV3YsisbJ" : {
        "message" : "hi",
        "uId" : "PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h1"
      },
      "-MfCfedXfFIvM2bZ3iYe" : {
        "message" : "hi",
        "uId" : "PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h1"
      },
      "-MfCllAO6qaGFI7FD1ud" : {
        "message" : "hi"
      },
      "-MfCnnPUTYUh5OW21fws" : {
        "message" : "hi"
      }
    },
    "PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h17V43IzF3QBh4wtn3NG6gW0xxNR03" : {
      "-MfCf3XpXtuQoUx1dKHh" : {
        "message" : "hi",
        "uId" : "PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h1"
      },
      "-MfCfeZ1ehufuG4dctXg" : {
        "message" : "hi",
        "uId" : "PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h1"
      },
      "-MfCll4UCdk24rTpjStb" : {
        "message" : "hi"
      },
      "-MfCnnJafzuCg1ZTrCI1" : {
        "message" : "hi"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Have you tried to set `String uId,message;` as private?

Comment: And? Is .getMessage() still return a null value?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes it still returns null value when I print it this is what i get I/System.out: Message= null.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting null?

Comment: There are many lines of code there. Which one produces that error?

Comment: Actually I am not getting a error I am getting the message as null instead of the correct message I tried to print the output of the function .getMessage used in this line ((SenverViewHolder)holder).senderMsg.setText(messagesModel.getMessage());

Comment: What does this line return `System.out.println(messagesModel.getMessage());`?

Comment: @AlexMamo it returns actually it should return the message but it is giving the value as null

Comment: @AlexMamo please help me solving my problem, I would be very grateful to you.

Comment: If you try to add `System.out.println(model.getMessage());` inside onDataChange, do you get something printed out in the logcat? Besides that, if you stop ignoring errors and use `System.out.println(error.getMessage());`, inside `onCancelled`, do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo There for the first print on model.getMessage I get I/System.out: Message = null  
and for the second one I dont even see the I/System.out statement

Comment: Is your `senderRoom` pointing to the right user?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes i think so as the uId is correct and also in the database the sent message is correctly displayed

Comment: If you try to display the content of the entire DataSnapshot object, do you also get null?

Comment: @AlexMamo you mean I print the snapshot?, if yes then this is what I get            I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h17V43IzF3QBh4wtn3NG6gW0xxNR03, value = {-MfD-d3u1WIo9LbSKAJW={uId=PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h1, message=hi}, -MfD0VV-DllCWZRKdnN1={uId=PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h1, message=hi}, -MfD0XKsGFxPB7wAFk9k={uId=PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h1, message=how to fo}} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last comment, where you said that you get the following output:

> I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h17V43IzF3QBh4wtn3NG6gW0xxNR03, value = {-MfD-d3u1WIo9LbSKAJW={uId=PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h1, message=hi}, -MfD0VV-DllCWZRKdnN1={uId=PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h1, message=hi}, -MfD0XKsGFxPB7wAFk9k={uId=PLYNSjgHfpMKZ3M2pVJcH2NqM5h1, message=how to fo}} }

It means that problem is in the following lines of code:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    messagesModel.clear();
    for(DataSnapshot snapshot1:snapshot.getChildren()){
        MessagesModel model = snapshot.getValue(MessagesModel.class);
        messagesModel.add(model);
     }
     chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Where you are looping through the wrong `DataSnapshot` object. So please change the following line:

```
MessagesModel model = snapshot.getValue(MessagesModel.class);
```

To:

```
MessagesModel model = snapshot1.getValue(MessagesModel.class);
//                            ^
```

`snapshot1` is the correct object.